# Using Webpack, can you use Google's closure compiler with HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am currently using Webpack with the HtmlWebpackPlugin to transpile and minify my code and create a HTML document from a template.

I was wondering if there is any way of using Google's closure compiling instead of using babel?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-closure-compiler

Below is my current plugin code which works with Babel to transpile the code.

```
plugins:
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'TestExport.html',
        template: './Resources/TestExport/TestExportTemplate.html',
        inject: false,
        custom: require("@babel/core").transformSync(fs.readFileSync('./Resources/TestExport/js/custom.js', 'utf8'), {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
        }).code,
        style: fs.readFileSync('./Resources/TestExport/css/style.css', 'utf8'),
        minify: {
            html5: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            minifyCSS: true,
            minifyJS: true
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The https://www.npmjs.com/package/closure-webpack-plugin plugin is the one maintained by the Closure team. And yes - it can co-exist with the HtmlWebpackPlugin.

Comment: Thanks for this, do you know if there is anywhere which gives an example similiar to the above? require("@babel/core").transformSync(fs.readFileSync('./Resources/TestExport/js/custom.js', 'utf8'), {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
        }).code

Comment: You probably don't need babel - let closure-compiler handle your transpilation using the language_out flag.